# Why does MIX dependencies have a "~>" before the semantic version of the dependency?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

On `mix.exs` you can declare dependencies like:

```
def deps do
  [{:plug, "~> 1.0"}]
end
```

Why does it need to have "~>" instead of simply the version on the second part of the tuple.

I have seen that if it gets the dependency from git, you can write the dependency like:

```
def deps do
  [{:plug, git: "git://github.com/elixir-lang/plug.git"}]
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This fancy arrow is supported by [Version](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Version.html) module. It rounds your dependency with precision set by the digit, which is left neighbour of the most specific one.

From the docs:

> ```
> # 2.0.0 and later until 2.1.0
> ">= 2.0.0 and < 2.1.0"
> ```
>
> Since the example above is such a common requirement, it can be expressed as:
>
> ```
> "~> 2.0.0"
> ```

Check more examples in the `Version` module.

Basically it's for your convinience, because it allows you to upgrade your deps automatically whenever you do `mix deps.upgrade`, but it lets you control the upgrade - you could download the upgrade, which crashes your current codebase etc.